# How to modify text in tbl_summary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'd like to modify, in tbl_summary "Median (IQR)" by "median [Q1 : Q3]", and "Range" by "Min -Max" ?

I'd like that in the far left colomn, we'd read  "median [Q1 : Q3]" instead of "Median (IQR)"

```
trial %>% select(trt, age) %>% 
tbl_summary(by = trt,
 type = list(all_continuous()  ~ "continuous2",
  all_categorical() ~ "categorical"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous()~ c("{N_nonmiss}",
                                        "{min} - {max}", 
                                        "{mean} ({sd})",
                                        "{median} [{p25} - {p75}]")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `add_stat_label()` function from the same package.

```r
library(gtsummary)
trial |> 
  select(trt, age) |> 
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              type = list(all_continuous()  ~ "continuous2",
                          all_categorical() ~ "categorical"),
              statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}",
                                                    "{min} - {max}",
                                                    "{mean} ({sd})",
                                                    "{median} [{p25} - {p75}]"))) |> 
  add_stat_label(label = list(all_continuous() ~ c("N",
                                                   "Min - Max",
                                                   "Mean (SD)",
                                                   "Median [Q1 : Q3]")))
```

See the [documentation](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_stat_label.html) for more info.

Comment: That's for "footnotes", not for the table, right ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it reproducible? As in, adding sample data (in code format) and the code that you've used so far. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: And your expected output. It's not clear what do you mean with "for the table".

Comment: I edited my post for the table I meant the output, in particular I want to modify the far left column

Comment: I am sorry, Andrea M, I do not see what is wrong in my question.

Comment: Thanks for editing, it's clear now. I've updated my answer.